# How can I approximate the Hessian matrix in convex optimization?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, convex-optimization

I can manually find the exact second order partial derivatives but the computation takes a big too long.

I know that I can find linear approximation to the gradient via 
$ f(x) \approx f(x_{0}) + \nabla f(x_{0})*(x-x_{0}) $

but how can I approximate the hessian matrix? I feel like I might have to use taylor approximation but I'm not sure

Comment: $f(x+h)\sim f(x) + \langle\nabla f(x),h\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\langle  \operatorname{Hess} f(x) h,h \rangle$

Comment: Google finite difference or quasi newton.

Comment: Might want to look at "complex step differentiation", if you can evaluate your functions at complex arguments.